# c# Get object property from ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

Can't figure this one out

I have an ArrayList of classes:

```
        // Holds an image
        public class productImage
        {
            public int imageID;
            public string imageURL;
            public DateTime dateAdded;
            public string slideTitle;
            public string slideDescrip;
        }

    public ArrayList productImages = new ArrayList();

productImage newImage = new productImage();
newImage.imageID = 123;
productImages.Add(newImage);
```

Now how do I access the property?

```
int something = productImages[0].imageID
```

Doesn't work!

> Error 1   'object' does not contain a
>   definition for 'slideTitle' and no
>   extension method 'slideTitle'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: Don't use arraylists in .net 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The values in an `ArrayList` are typed to `Object`.  You need to cast to `productImage` to access the property.

```
int something = ((productImage)productImages[0]).imageId;
```

A much better solution though is to used a strongly typed collection like `List<T>`.  You can specify the element type is `productImage` and avoid the casting altogether.

```
public List<productImage> productImages = new List<productImage>();
productImage newImage = new productImage();
newImage.imageID = 123;
productImages.Add(newImage);
int something = productImages[0].imageID;  // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 int something = ((productImage)productImages[0]).imageID;
```

Needs to be casted from the type object.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this code up with modern idioms:

```
public ArrayList productImages = new ArrayList();

productImage newImage = new productImage();
newImage.imageID = 123;
productImages.Add(newImage);
```

can be re-written as:

```
var productImages = new List<ProductImage> { new ProductImage { ImageID = 123 } };
```

Comment: Thanks, but I reduced the code in the question for simplicity, the actual code is in a loop getting database records