# get specific value from ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I am using ArrayList in Asp.net I want to extract specific items . My code is

```
ArrayList items = (ArrayList)Session["mycart"];
foreach(var v in items)
{



}
```

but this is not working . I want to get value like

```
v.myvalue;
```

My arralist is filled with several items coming from prevoius page.

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Get object property from ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669392/c-sharp-get-object-property-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that ArrayList stores all elements as `object`. You need to perform a cast to the type of object that contains `myvalue`.
For example

```
ArrayList items = (ArrayList)Session["mycart"];
foreach(var v in items)
{
     MyObject o = v as MyObject;
     if (o != null)
     {
         // do stuff with o.myvalue
     }
}
```

It may be better to just use the generic `List` class rather `ArrayList`, although you may have a perfectly reason for doing otherwise. Generally, you should use the generic (e.g. `List<MyObject>`), not only for performance but also ease of use.

Comment: Exactly I changed ArrayList to generic List and now its working